# How to receive byte from USB using LUFA for AT90USB162?

Tags: c, usb, avr

using LUFA demo from: /Demos/Device/ClassDriver/VirtualSerial/

I cleared all the code of garbage (joystick and LEDs), all that was left was this:

```
#include "VirtualSerial.h"

USB_ClassInfo_CDC_Device_t VirtualSerial_CDC_Interface =
    {
        .Config =
            {
                .ControlInterfaceNumber   = INTERFACE_ID_CDC_CCI,
                .DataINEndpoint           =
                    {
                        .Address          = CDC_TX_EPADDR,
                        .Size             = CDC_TXRX_EPSIZE,
                        .Banks            = 1,
                    },
                .DataOUTEndpoint =
                    {
                        .Address          = CDC_RX_EPADDR,
                        .Size             = CDC_TXRX_EPSIZE,
                        .Banks            = 1,
                    },
                .NotificationEndpoint =
                    {
                        .Address          = CDC_NOTIFICATION_EPADDR,
                        .Size             = CDC_NOTIFICATION_EPSIZE,
                        .Banks            = 1,
                    },
            },
    };

/** Standard file stream for the CDC interface when set up, so that the virtual CDC COM port can be
 *  used like any regular character stream in the C APIs.
 */
static FILE USBSerialStream;


int main(void)
{
    SetupHardware();

    /* Create a regular character stream for the interface so that it can be used with the stdio.h functions */
    CDC_Device_CreateStream(&VirtualSerial_CDC_Interface, &USBSerialStream);

    GlobalInterruptEnable();

    for (;;)
    {

        /* Must throw away unused bytes from the host, or it will lock up while waiting for the device */
        CDC_Device_ReceiveByte(&VirtualSerial_CDC_Interface);
        char echo = 0;
        echo = CDC_Device_ReceiveByte(&VirtualSerial_CDC_Interface);
        if(echo)
        {
            fprintf(&USBSerialStream, "Byte received: %c\n\r", echo);
        }

        CDC_Device_USBTask(&VirtualSerial_CDC_Interface);
        USB_USBTask();
        
        // fputs("hello\n\r", &USBSerialStream);
    }
}

/** Configures the board hardware and chip peripherals for the demo's functionality. */
void SetupHardware(void)
{
#if (ARCH == ARCH_AVR8)
    /* Disable watchdog if enabled by bootloader/fuses */
    MCUSR &= ~(1 << WDRF);
    wdt_disable();

    /* Disable clock division */
    clock_prescale_set(clock_div_1);
#endif

    /* Hardware Initialization */
    USB_Init();
}



/** Event handler for the library USB Connection event. */
void EVENT_USB_Device_Connect(void)
{
}

/** Event handler for the library USB Disconnection event. */
void EVENT_USB_Device_Disconnect(void)
{
}

/** Event handler for the library USB Configuration Changed event. */
void EVENT_USB_Device_ConfigurationChanged(void)
{
    bool ConfigSuccess = true;

    ConfigSuccess &= CDC_Device_ConfigureEndpoints(&VirtualSerial_CDC_Interface);

}

/** Event handler for the library USB Control Request reception event. */
void EVENT_USB_Device_ControlRequest(void)
{
    CDC_Device_ProcessControlRequest(&VirtualSerial_CDC_Interface);
}

/** CDC class driver callback function the processing of changes to the virtual
 *  control lines sent from the host..
 *
 *  \param[in] CDCInterfaceInfo  Pointer to the CDC class interface configuration structure being referenced
 */
void EVENT_CDC_Device_ControLineStateChanged(USB_ClassInfo_CDC_Device_t *const CDCInterfaceInfo)
{
    /* You can get changes to the virtual CDC lines in this callback; a common
       use-case is to use the Data Terminal Ready (DTR) flag to enable and
       disable CDC communications in your application when set to avoid the
       application blocking while waiting for a host to become ready and read
       in the pending data from the USB endpoints.
    */
    bool HostReady = (CDCInterfaceInfo->State.ControlLineStates.HostToDevice & CDC_CONTROL_LINE_OUT_DTR) != 0;
}
```

The microcontroller is detected by the computer, the com port receives the message (Byte received: ) is displayed in the terminal program.
I'm trying to configure it to echo the byte of the sent character, but I only see an infinite FF (even without sending the character) on the output:

> [docklight_screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDzTn.jpg)